# Gnome Encfs Manager, data recover

Tags: gnome, data-recovery, encfs

I removed the stash with data from manager. Is there a way to recover stash with data? 
Testdisk about my folder when I try to recover it: No file found, filesystem may be damaged.

Comment: Sorry but at least to me it’s not clear what you are actually asking. Please try to rephrase and give some more details.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Hidden folder does not exist. I see this folder in testdisk, but when I try to restore it -  an error occurs: No file found, filesystem may be damaged. A separate Linux partition (ext4) on the hard drive, the folder was there. Tell me what the technical details do I add? If this problem still can solve.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you selected to remove the stash from the file system too. In that case encfs manager seems to delete the encrypted folder. Do you still see the encrypted folder? It might be hidden, i.e. starting with '.'.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Hidden folder does not exist. I see this folder in testdisk, but when I try to restore it - an error occurs: No file found, filesystem may be damaged. A separate Linux partition (ext4) on the hard drive, the folder was there.